# Alternative ways for interpretation of odds

Tags: logistic

I am reading the second edition of Categorical Data Analysis by Alan Agresti, and somehow stuck in the following second paragraph:
[image]

I don't quite understand why $\beta\pi(\hat{x})(1 - \pi(\hat{x}))$ will give the probability when $x = 26.3$, can anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is near the bottom of [p166](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hpEzw4T0sPUC&pg=PA166). It's using a linear approximation (what social scientists would call a 'marginal effect'). A small change $\delta x$ in $x$ gives a change in probability of:
$$\delta\pi \approx \frac{\partial \pi(x)}{\partial x} \delta x.$$
With $\operatorname{logit}(\pi(x)) = \alpha + \beta x$, it's straightforward to show that
$ \partial \pi(x) / \partial x = \beta \pi(x)(1-\pi(x))$.